# NSTextView with Smart Quotes disabled, still replaces quotes

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa

I have a NSTextView with the 'Smart Quotes' option disabled:

[image: Smart Quotes disabled]

However, if I were to type:

'hello world'

Into the textview, it instanly gets replaced with:

‘hello world’

(see how the single quotes have been replaced).

I thought disabling smart quotes would have taken care of this, but it does not seem to of helped. Any suggestions on how I can get these prettier quotes to go away?

Comment: This is a bug in NSTextView, not something that Interface Builder can control. Please file bugs at bugreport.apple.com and reference radar://12868213

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You can disable smart quotes for your NSTextView with:

```
self.textView.automaticQuoteSubstitutionEnabled = NO;
```

Not setting the checkmark in the interface builder doesn't seem to work since OS X 10.9 Mavericks.

See [NSTextView setAutomaticQuoteSubstitutionEnabled:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTextView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSTextView/setAutomaticQuoteSubstitutionEnabled%3a)

Also you can use this for a more detailed control over the text replacement.

```
self.textView.enabledTextCheckingTypes = 0;
```

See [NSTextView setEnabledTextCheckingTypes:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTextView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSTextView/setEnabledTextCheckingTypes%3a)

Also in Mavericks there is smart quotes enabled by default in System Preferences → Keyboard → Text. You can disable this as a personal preference.

Comment: This problem is still not fixed as of Yosemite Xcode 6.1.

Comment: This is a bug in NSTextView, not something that Interface Builder can control. Please file bugs at http://bugreport.apple.com and reference radar://12868213.

Comment: `NSTextView` overrides the settings in the storyboard with the user preferences. I don't think this is a bug. If you want to override the user preferences then change the settings in code.

Comment: This worked for me, thanks so much!

Answer (score 12):

This problem is still not fixed as of Yosemite / Xcode 6.1

To turn off all the substitution options that IB seems to ignore, I had to do this:

```
self.textView.automaticQuoteSubstitutionEnabled = NO;
self.textView.automaticDashSubstitutionEnabled = NO;
self.textView.automaticTextReplacementEnabled = NO;
```

Answer (score 6):

Xcode 7.3 still have this problem.

The way to set these properties in IB.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

**Swift 4 extension to make any NSTextView monospace**

- good for JSON editing
- Turns off smart quotes
- uses monospaced font
- can be done in IB but I had problems

**Usage:**

```
 @IBOutlet var textViewJSONPushBody: NSTextView!
 @IBOutlet var textViewConsole: NSTextView!

  ... viewDidLoad(){
         //JSON editor - larger font
         self.textViewJSONPushBody.makePlainText(withFontSize: 12.0)

         //Log view - smaller
         //defaults to sys font - small size
         self.textViewConsole.makePlainText()
         //or set fontSize
         self.textViewConsole.makePlainText(withFontSize: 10.0)
    }
```

**NSTextView+PlainText.swift**

```
//
//  NSTextView+PlainText.swift
//  GetStarted_NH_MacOS
//
//  Created by Brian Clear on 12/07/2018.
//  Copyright © 2018 City of London Consulting Limited. All rights reserved.
//

import Foundation
import AppKit

extension NSTextView{

    /*
     Usage:
        @IBOutlet var textViewJSONPushBody: NSTextView!
        viewDidLoad(){
            //JSON editor
            self.textViewJSONPushBody.makePlainText(withFontSize: 12.0)

            //Log view - smaller
            //defaults to sys font - small size
            self.textViewConsole.makePlainText()
            self.textViewConsole.makePlainText(withFontSize: 10.0)
        }
     */
    func makePlainText(withFontSize 
                          fontSize: CGFloat = NSFont.smallSystemFontSize)
    {

        //---------------------------------------------------------
        //FONT - monospaced
        //---------------------------------------------------------
        //small font
        //self.font = NSFont.userFixedPitchFont(ofSize: NSFont.smallSystemFontSize)

        //medium font
        self.font = NSFont.userFixedPitchFont(ofSize: NSFont.systemFontSize)

        //---------------------------------------------------------
        self.isRulerVisible = false
        self.isFieldEditor = false
        self.isRichText = false

        //---------------------------------------------------------
        //smart quotes mess up json
        //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19801601/nstextview-with-smart-quotes-disabled-still-replaces-quotes
        self.isAutomaticQuoteSubstitutionEnabled = false

         //---------------------------------------------------------
        self.isAutomaticLinkDetectionEnabled = false
        self.isContinuousSpellCheckingEnabled = false
        self.isGrammarCheckingEnabled = false
        self.isAutomaticDashSubstitutionEnabled = false
        self.isAutomaticDataDetectionEnabled = false
        self.isAutomaticSpellingCorrectionEnabled = false
        self.isAutomaticTextReplacementEnabled = false
        self.isIncrementalSearchingEnabled = false
        self.isAutomaticTextCompletionEnabled = false
        //---------------------------------------------------------
        //see also
        //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19801601/nstextview-with-smart-quotes-disabled-still-replaces-quotes
        //self.enabledTextCheckingTypes =
         //---------------------------------------------------------

    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Swift 5 solution:

```swift
self.textview.smartQuotesType = .no
self.textview.smartDashesType = .no
```