# Testing string for double quote characters in Swift

Tags: swift, string, if-statement, double-quotes

I am trying to find double quote characters in a swift String type with the following code:

```
for char in string {
    if char == "\"" {
        debugPrint("I have found a double quote")
    }
}
```

The if statement never catches the double quote in the string.

I am using Xcode 7.3.1

Any suggestions of comments?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on what you want to do:

```
let str = "Hello \"World\""

// If you simply want to know if the string has a double quote
if str.containsString("\"") {
    print("String contains a double quote")
}

// If you want to know index of the first double quote
if let range = str.rangeOfString("\"") {
    print("Found double quote at", range.startIndex)
}

// If you want to know the indexes of all double quotes
let indexes = str.characters.enumerate()
                .filter { $1 == "\"" }
                .map { $0.0 }
print(indexes)
```

Comment: All of the examples given fail if I am searching for a double quote.  If I search for an 'a' they all succeed in finding it in the string.  I am wondering if I have found a bug in Swift?

Comment: I actually am trying to iterate through the characters in the string to find text that is bounded in double quotes so I can extract it.

Comment: If I try your examples in a separate application designed for testing it works.  HMMMMMM!

Comment: When I use the following code after reading the line from a file, the code will not find the \" character:

init(line: String) {
        
        super.init()
        
        let tkns = line.componentsSeparatedByString(" ")
        
        for tk in tkns {
            if tk.containsString("\"") {
                print("I found a quote")
            }
            self.tokens.append(Token(token: tk))
        }
    }

Any thoughts?

Comment: Place a breakpoint in the for loop and run it through a debugger. I don't have enough data to know what's going on

Comment: I have basically the same problem when I try to test for operators also.  The code:

var operators: [String] = ["+", "-", "*", "/"]

func isOperator(oper: String) {
    for op in self.operators {
        if oper = op {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}

always returns false

Comment: I have set a breakpoint and examined the test for double quotes and it always just goes right past it even though it shouldn't.  I am using an NSTextView to edit the text.  I obtain the lines from it.  Could that be a problem?

Comment: Does your code even compile? Off the top of my head: `=` should be `==`; your func should return `Bool` not `void`

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that code should even compile? (Assuming `string` is indeed a string.)

Try this instead. Seems to work for me (same Xcode version):

```
for char in string.characters {
    if char == "\"" {
        print("I have found a double quote")
    }
}
```

Comment: Still goes right by it. I solved the operators problem by placing the operator I was testing in the array of operators.  An oversight.  It seems that the only character I am having trouble with is the double quote character.

Comment: @doodle I've tested this code myself, and it worked for me. If you share the exact code you're running, I can try that.

Comment: Also, I have absolutely no idea what this sentence is talking about: "I solved the operators problem by placing the operator I was testing in the array of operators."

Comment: It was an earlier comment.  Disregard. I will post the exact function code that I am using.

Comment: I have been able to get it to work in another test application.  It is just this application where I have been taking the text to parse out of an NSTextView.  Also I am using the document template that Xcode provides so I also don't know what it is doing to the file that is read.

Comment: @doodle My guess is that you actually have a different character than the ASCII double quote you're looking for.

Comment: Here is the code.  It is just the code that you suggested.  In reference to your last comment, I am just using the one from the keyboard.  Don't know how I could get the wrong one.

init(line: String) {
        
        super.init()
        
        // Prepare string literals
        for char in line.characters {
            if char == "\"" {
                print("I have found a double quote")
            }
        }
        
        let tkns = line.componentsSeparatedByString(" ")
        
        for tk in tkns {
            self.tokens.append(Token(token: tk))
        }

Comment: @doodle I meant code including the actual value of `line`.

Comment: @doodle See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19801601/nstextview-with-smart-quotes-disabled-still-replaces-quotes for what I suspect is happening. (The quote is being replaced with a different character.)

Comment: Sorry about the code in the comment but I can't see how to make the code pretty in the grey box now.

Comment: The text that I am trying to parse is:

WAIT FOR “>”

Comment: @doodle The text you just pasted here indeed does not have a `"` in it. It has `“` and `”` instead. (Hopefully you can see the difference.)

Comment: Now that you pointed that out I went to the NSTextView and it does replace the double quote with the open and close quote. HMMMMMMM....  Back to the documentation.   Thanks so much for your time.

Comment: There is a function call named "NSTextView.toggleAutomaticQuoteSubstitution(sender: AnyObj)" that you need to call to turn off automatic quote substitution.  Works fine now.  Thanks again.