# How to Disable macOs TextView Substitutions in Swift 3

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, cocoa

Why does this happen in a Text View? (I think I've turned OFF all substitutions in XCode):

[image: substitutions]

I am creating a simple macOs Cocoa (GUI) program, using the Swift 3 language (instead of Objective-C). XCode version is 8.2.1. Swift version is 3.0.2.

I added a "Text View: to the storyboard View Controller window (in Main.storyboard), and created an Outlet for it in code (ViewController.swift). When inspecting the "View Controller Scene", my TextView is nested like this: Scroll View > Clip View > Text View.

[image: XCode Layout details]

The generated outlet looks like this:

```
@IBOutlet weak var txtWindow: NSScrollView!
```

I am able to set text, clear text, populate text from a file, etc. just fine.

However, whenever I set text with 2 dashes (whether the source is read from a file, or typed manually), the text view window automatically substitutes it with an em-dash (a single character - a longer dash). I would like to disable this auto-correct substitution behavior, and keep dashes unaltered.

Also, the same substitution occurs when three dots/periods are entered (ellipsis). I don't want the fancy ellipsis character to show up - just keep the three periods.

[image: XCode Settings]

It seems like I have turned off all substitutions, but it continues to happen when typing in the text box. What am I missing?

Comment: It looks like you created an outlet for the scroll view instead of the text view. How many textviews do you have?

Comment: A textview is nested inside this scrollview, then there is 1 other "Secure Text Field" where its outlet is an NSTextField.

Comment: How do you set the text?

Comment: txtWindow.documentView!.insertText(my_variable!). However, this substitution behavior works via code, but also when I type free-hand into the text view.

Comment: It appears that this is a bug; see [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19801601/nstextview-with-smart-quotes-disabled-still-replaces-quotes). I have to turn of substitutions in code for now.

Answer (score 2):

Currently, this is a bug in xcode. Here is a reference to further details:

[Smart Quotes disabled Still Replaces Quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19801601/nstextview-with-smart-quotes-disabled-still-replaces-quotes)

I have to turn off substitutions in the code still, for this to function correctly.

Comment: Your link helped me, thanks for sharing it @MiStr. Can you mark your answer as correct so it's more obvious to people?